# How to add a column in result set and set values in that field?

Tags: mysql

I have two tables

**people**

```
name    id

man1    456
man2    123
man3    789
```

**notes**

```
content id

testing 123
hello   456
```

I have two queries that select records from the table `people` if a note for that person exists.

`SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID FROM NOTES)`

```
name    id

man1    456
man2    123
```

And

SELECT * FROM PEOPLE WHERE ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM NOTES)

```
name    id

man3    789
```

I would like to create a column in the result set (not in the actual table) and set the value of the field based on whether a note exists.

```
name    id  does_note_exist

man1    456 yes
man2    123 yes
man3    789 no
```

What is the appropriate syntax to do this?  Something like this would be what I'm looking for:

```
IF ID IN (SELECT ID FROM NOTES)
   does_note_exist = yes        

IF ID NOT IN (SELECT ID FROM NOTES)
   does_note_exist = no
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a `LEFT OUTER JOIN`:

```
SELECT 
    p.id, 
    p.name,
    CASE WHEN n.id IS NULL THEN 'no' ELSE 'yes' END AS does_note_exist
FROM people p
LEFT OUTER JOIN notes n
ON n.id = p.id
GROUP BY n.id
```

Comment: Thanks so much.  In some cases I have more than one note per person. In those cases I just want to check if at least 1 note exists and if at least one note exists, then retrieve `p.id`, `p.name` and `does_note_exist`.  Is there a way I can do that?

Comment: @LedZeppelin, I updated the answer, it's simpler than I thought earlier. Just use n.id on the `CASE WHEN ...`, and also `GROUP BY n.id`. This way, you'll only have one result per person, and the yes/no will be correct too.

Answer (score 0):

There are a bunch of ways you might do that - I think I would use a case statement:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html